# ENTITIES type in XML spec

Tags: xml

As I was reading the XML specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml) and I came across something that didn't make any sense to me:

> appearing either as the value of an attribute which has been declared as type **ENTITY**, or as one of the space-separated tokens in the value of an attribute which has been declared as type **ENTITIES**

From this section: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#entproc

> The Name identifies the entity in an entity reference or, in the case of an unparsed entity, in the value of an **ENTITY** or **ENTITIES** attribute

From this section: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-entity-decl

I'm well aware on how to declare an entity using the `<!ENTITY ...>` syntax, however I've never seen a DTD structure containing `<!ENTITIES ...>`. Furthermore, I've looked at the source for common XML parsers/processors and they don't seem to handle that case. Lastly, the [XML spec for entities](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-entity-decl) itself doesn't even define a grammar for constructing one.

Did I read the documentation wrong? Is **ENTITIES** not a thing? If so, why is it mentioned in the spec as a separate type?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Though there's this

https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/blob/5f1f1f1d98fef39ef885d4271029b4c3fd814a2d/expat/tests/runtests.c#L993

```
START_TEST(test_attr_whitespace_normalization)
{
    const char *text =
        "<!DOCTYPE doc [\n"
        "  <!ATTLIST doc\n"
        "            attr NMTOKENS #REQUIRED\n"
        "            ents ENTITIES #REQUIRED\n"
        "            refs IDREFS   #REQUIRED>\n"
        "]>\n"
        "<doc attr='    a  b c\t\td\te\t' refs=' id-1   \t  id-2\t\t'  \n"
        "     ents=' ent-1   \t\r\n"
        "            ent-2  ' >\n"
        "  <e id='id-1'/>\n"
        "  <e id='id-2'/>\n"
"</doc>";
```

(before edit...)

The spec is unclear, and the only reference I could find to ENTITIES is in the RFC3151 URN description of Public identifiers, in "-//{owner}//{class} {description}//" format ; this comes from OASIS rather than W3, iirc.

But you probably figured that out already ..

See

- https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/14809/xml-catalogs.html#s.example
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3151.txt
- http://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/4.5/ch02.html#ch.create.pubids

Examples

/etc/xml/docbook-xml.xml

```
<delegatePublic publicIdStartString="-//OASIS//ENTITIES DocBook Notations V4.4//EN"
  catalog="file:///usr/share/xml/docbook/schema/dtd/4.4/catalog.xml"/>
<delegatePublic publicIdStartString="-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DocBook Document Hierarchy V4.2//EN"
  catalog="file:///usr/share/xml/docbook/schema/dtd/4.2/catalog.xml"/>
```

/usr/share/xml/docbook/schema/dtd/4.4/catalog.xml

```
<public publicId="-//OASIS//ENTITIES DocBook Notations V4.4//EN"
  uri="dbnotnx.mod"/>
<public publicId="-//OASIS//ENTITIES DocBook Character Entities V4.4//EN"
  uri="dbcentx.mod"/>
```

dbcentx.mod

```
<![%sgml.features;[
    <!ENTITY % ISOamsa.module "INCLUDE">
    <![ %ISOamsa.module; [
        <!ENTITY % ISOamsa PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Arrow Relations//EN">
    ]]>
    <!ENTITY % ISOamsb.module "INCLUDE">
    <![ %ISOamsb.module; [
        <!ENTITY % ISOamsb PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Binary Operators//EN">
    ]]>
```

Comment: Good finds, although I feel like this is still somewhat unresolved

Comment: http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/attlist_declaration.shtml#EntitiesEx

    ENTITIES  Allows multiple ENTITY names separated by whitespacevalidity constraint. See example.